# Complex table layout with fixed width and expanding columns

Tags: css, tablelayout, fluid-layout, fixed-width

I have a complex table layout ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RVSbJ/)). This is a long report with many sections and each section has a table in it.

The first two columns of the tables should have a fixed width to make sure they align nicely.

The third column should grow to fit the text inside of it without wrapping (it's always a single word).

The last column should always fill the remaining space.

When I just specify the widths of the first two columns and give the last column 100% width, then the last column fills the available space (good) but the widths of the first two columns are ignored.

When I give the table `table-layout: fixed;`, then the width of the first two columns works but the last two columns occupy the same screen space since I can't give the third column a fixed width.

Is there a solution for this?

Note: The solution doesn't need to work on IE! FF 12+ and Chome 21+ is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify a general table with (e.g. '100%'). Then you only need to specify the widths of the first two columns. Therefore the two others behave like desired.

[Here is the fixed fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fant/mcZkD/7/)

In a nutshell:

- Remove `td.type { width: 100%; }​`
- Add `width:0.1em;` to `td.name`

Comment: As you can see in the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RVSbJ/, I already did that and it doesn't work.

Comment: Remove the `td.type { width: 100%; }`.

Comment: That works but it looks a bit ugly because the free space is now split between the last two columns. Is there a way to make only the last column grow?

Comment: Not pretty, but adding `width:0;` to `td.name` solves this problem.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work for me. Can you please update the jsfiddle to show how it works?

Comment: Sorry, you already wrote that on your question. Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fant/mcZkD/7/)